# polymer starter kit open url with multi level path

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

In the starter-kit when I run using 'gulp serve' and enter an url with more than one level path for e.g. localhost:5000/register/user then it fails. It basically looks for elements.html in localhost:5000/register/elements/elements.html rather than localhost:5000/elements/elements.html.

However when I open the link by clicking from another page, it works. Any idea how to make this work when I enter the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Are you implementing your own logic for the `register` page? Or are you working off of a tutorial? Because that page does not exist in the default Polymer Starter Kit (PSK). Please add a comment to this answer.

If you have implemented a `register` page, edit `app/elements/routing.html` to define the routing rules for the page.

Solution 2:

Do you have the hashbang rule enabled still? When I run `gulp serve` and then click the **Users** nav menu item it takes me to `http://localhost:5000/#!/users`.

So if you still have the following rule enabled in `routing.html`:

```
// add #! before urls
page({
  hashbang: true
});
```

Perhaps that is messing you up. Try setting `hashbang` to `false`.

Comment: Yes, I have created a register route. I am able to open the link when I click it from another page like 'localhost:5000/login'. Its not opening when I enter the complete url in the browser.

Comment: I'm not going off of reproducible data here, so I'm just throwing out ideas :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its not set to true.

Comment: Its part of an application I am developing. It might take some time for me to port it to jsbin.